# Python IDE or module which caches results?

Tags: python, caching, ide, automation, nltk

I am working with a few corpora included in nltk-data from [nltk](http://nltk.org/) to figure out certain algorithms.

So my code would generally be something of the style:

```
import re, nltk, random
from nltk.corpus import reuters

def find_test_and_train_data():
    return [fileid for fileid in reuters.fileids() if re.match(r"^training/", fileid)], [fileid for fileid in reuters.fileids() if re.match(r"^test/", fileid)]

def generate_random_data(train_and_test_fileids):
    random.seed(348) ; random.shuffle(train_and_test_fileids[0])
    return train_and_test_fileids[0][2000:], train_and_test_fileids[0][:2000]

def fileid_words(fileid):
    return [word.lower() for line in reuters.words(fileid) for word in line.split() if re.match('^[A-Za-z]+$', word)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_fileids, dev_fileids = generate_random_data(find_test_and_train_data())
    train_data=fileid_words(train_fileids)
    dev_data=fileid_words(dev_fileids)
```

So if I run it into an interactive interpreter I can then perform tasks on `train_data`, `dev_data` and their corresponding fileids without repopulating the variables (a very time consuming task).

However, I want to be able to write it into a *.py* file so that I can save statistically interesting algorithms.

I could do this by double-typing, e.g.: when I get a function working in the interpreter I then copy+paste it into the .py file, but this is quite inefficient and I lose out on my IDEs' features.

Are there any IDEs or Python modules which can automatically keep the Python script running in memory, or store the value of a variable—such as `test_data`—in a db?

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The python-specific way to do this is with pickle:

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

You can just save variables to disk and then load them back:

```
import pickle

data1 = {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
     'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
     'c': None}
output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')
pickle.dump(data1, output)
output.close()

input = open('data.pkl', 'rb')

data1 = pickle.load(pkl_file)
```

If you want to save in a format that will be compatible with other languages in the future, consider JSON.

Comment: Is unpickling much faster than processing with NLTK's `.words()`?

Comment: I would expect so, but it should be pretty easy to do a test using the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that use inspect module to gain codes string from that and that save it into a file.py.
If you use inspect module, you will be able to gain code objects and event source code and then be able to get raw code into string, then put it to a persistent storage like file.

Comment: But it is already in persistent storage (albeit inefficiently). I'm not familiar with the inspect module, maybe you can give me a code sample showing this to be more efficient than aforementioned?